# Calculating space complexity

Tags: complexity-theory

I was given this sample of code and im not sure what the space complexity will be here.

```
void f1(int n){
    int b = 2;
    while (n >= 1){
        b *= b;
        n /= 2;
    }
    free(malloc(b));
}
```

As far as the loop, it runs log(n) times, but the variable `b` is increased exponentially.

Thats why im not sure whats going on.

Thanks for any help regarding this :)

Comment: Space complexity refers to the additional memory space you need to allocate for your algorithm. Here you have used only one integer, nothing else. So the space complexity is constant or O(1)

Comment: @AnkushPandit he asks about memory allocated by malloc.

Comment: @CPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPP Nothing to do with the malloc call, the size provided in the malloc call is independent of the size n, hence constant.

Comment: @AnkushPandit `b` is independent from `n`? How is that?

Comment: Because the memory allocated to an `int` is fixed, and does not dynamically change with the contents inside it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you run that as it is then you would get a memory overflow since most numeric datatypes have limited memory (e.g. 32 bits). Therefore I will assume that you run that algorithm on a Turing machine which is an idealized computer model. In that case n will be much smaller then the last value of b. In addition, I assume that your goal is to compute the last value of b, so you need to write the value of b on the memory at the end (say in binary). Keeping these in mind you only need to use enough space record all values of b on the memory (tape). You wouldn't need much more memory than to record the last value b takes. Therefore your space complexity is $O(2^{2^{log_2(n)}})$ which is simply O(2^n)